# 22.04 l2tp client not working

Tags: vpn

I just updated to 22.04 from 20.04 and my l2tp vpn stoped to work, tried some tutorials making a purge to xl2tpd and downloaded a old version but still not working, is there any workaround? i work remotely and need to activate vpn to connect to the services.

```
sudo apt remove --purge xl2tpd
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xl2tpd/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xl2tpd\_1.3.12-1.1\_amd64.deb
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
sudo reboot
```

added credentials again => failed to activate network connection

Comment: There is a new xl2tpd package in 22.04 Updates to replace the broken xl2tpd ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/xl2tpd ).
If it still doesn't work, you have some other issue and is hard to tell without looking at the output of `journalctl -b --no-hostname _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service + SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=pppd`

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered the same issue after upgrading popos to 22.04.
Below are the steps that resolved my issue. You can try it.

#### Step 1

`sudo apt remove --purge xl2tpd`

#### Step 2

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xl2tpd/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb`

#### Step 3

`sudo dpkg -i xl2tpd\_1.3.12-1.1\_amd64.deb`

#### Step 4

`sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome`

#### Step 5

`sudo service xl2tpd stop`

#### Step 6

`sudo reboot`

Comment: For me, neither this answer nor the Pilot6's answer worked. The command mentioned by Douglas Kosovic showed `Received out of order control packet on tunnel` so I followed https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd/issues/136 but nothing worked.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 2):

Liker our friend said:

```
sudo apt remove --purge xl2tpd
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xl2tpd/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
systemctl restart xl2tpd
```

Works on, ubuntu 22.04 with Mikrotik VPN Router.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solution here
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/u8uwzv/ubuntu_2204_lts_vpn_l2tp_stops_working/

the problem is newer xl2tpd likely doesnt compatible with l2tp

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment. It's fine to link to a post but this provides no value to other users. At least provide the fix in your answer or provide something that won't force other to go looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

- `sudo apt install golang-go`
- `go install "github.com/katalix/go-l2tp/...@latest"`
- `sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin`
- `sudo cp go/bin/kl2tpd /usr/local/sbin`

In that case, the Network Manager uses kl2tpd instead of xl2tpd.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions to use `xl2tpd-1.3.12`, as other uses have suggested, and also had to uncheck the IPsec Phase1 and Phase2 Algorithms. Previously I was using `Phase1 Algorithms: 3des-sha1-modp1024` and `Phase2 Algorithms: 3des-sha1`.
The defaults seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove libreswan!

```
sudo apt remove libreswan
```

I have the same problem.

```
sudo apt remove --purge xl2tpd
sudo apt remove  libreswan
wge  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xl2tpd/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
sudo reboot -f
...
sudo apt-mark hold xl2tpd
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234215)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue while upgrading the Ubuntu version to 22.04

This is what helped me to resolve the issue.

Install this package first -

```
sudo apt-get install libreswan network-manager-l2tp  network-manager-l2tp-gnome resolvconf
```

In IPsec Settings, enable `Enforce UDP encapsulation` and in PPP settings, only enable `MSCHAPv2`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you must use Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) connection.
In the context of VPNs, PPP is often used as the underlying protocol for L2TP/IPsec connections.

To create a new PPP configuration file for an L2TP/IPsec VPN connection, you can use the pppd command with a text editor to manually create the configuration file. Here's how:

Open a terminal window.

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Create a new configuration file in the /etc/ppp/peers directory with a unique name, such as myvpn:

   `sudo nano /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn`
3. Add the following lines to the configuration file:

```
ipparam myvpn
name <vpn_username>
password <vpn_password>
remotename <vpn_server_name>
require-mschap-v2
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
noauth
idle 1800
mtu 1410
mru 1410
defaultroute
persist
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
noipdefault
usepeerdns
```

Replace <vpn_username>, <vpn_password>, and <vpn_server_name> with the appropriate values for your VPN connection.

1. Save the file and exit the editor.
2. To establish the VPN connection, use the following command:

   `sudo pppd call myvpn`

Then you can run vpn connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have PopOS 20.04 fresh installed on my PC, and using PPTP my VPN works well, but after some OS updates it's broken, and never connect again. Later I know that my workplace VPN works best using L2TP.

Below are the steps that resolved my issue. You can try it.

1. sudo apt remove --purge xl2tpd
2. wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xl2tpd/xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
3. sudo dpkg -i xl2tpd_1.3.12-1.1_amd64.deb
4. sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
5. sudo service xl2tpd stop
6. sudo reboot

And after reboot

1. Create VPN using L2TP
2. Check "Use L2TP ephemeral source port"
3. Click on "IPSec Setting" and enabled, enter the Preshared Key from your VPN Provider (in my case my Network Admin)

Hope my case could help you, cheers.