# IPSec VPN Client on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I am trying to connect to a IPSec VPN on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. In the past this worked, but after upgrading from 20.04 it didnt. I deleted the configuration and trying to add it again using the UI.

My connection uses a IPSec group name and shared secret. Where do I enter the IPSec group name?

I followed this: https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#linux
I tried this: [22.04 l2tp client not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405854/22-04-l2tp-client-not-working)

Edit: I have these installed

```
$ sudo apt list network-manager-l2tp-gnome
network-manager-l2tp-gnome/jammy,now 1.20.0-1build2 amd64 [installed]
```

```
$ sudo apt -a list xl2tpd
xl2tpd/jammy-updates,now 1.3.16-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
xl2tpd/jammy 1.3.16-1 amd64
```

Comment: Note that `L2TP` alone is *not* IPSec, IPSec tends to use `L2TP` but is *not* just L2TP plain.  You need to know if your IPSec VPN is a Cisco VPN or IKEv1 VPN (which needs `network-manager-vpnc-gnome`) or a generic IPSec setup that uses IKE2 (which needs Strongswan - `network-manager-strongswan-gnome`).  If you do not know the type of VPN connection in use, then you cannot properly determine which of the IPSec VPN clients you need, though you should probably try with `network-manager-strongswan-gnome` first which is the stronger/newer IPSec library / suite in Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for your explanation. I will try to google more with this knowledge and try out strongswam. It is a Cisco VPN.

Comment: if it's a Cisco VPN you will need to use the `vpnc` option that I stated.  If you *know* it's a Cisco VPN IKEv1 endpoint then you need to use `vpnc`.